# Strange centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment

`\centering` command, that I use in my document gives strange output - values aren't centered equally

image below should let you understand (elements in red frame and two not framed "value" strings in table, are not centered)
[image]
code for this page/document:

```
\documentclass[twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.0cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\appendixtitle}[2]{\begin{center}(#1)\\ ~ \\ {\Large #2}\end{center}}
\newcolumntype{z}[1]{%
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}%
\newcommand{\tnl}{\tabularnewline}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{appendices}
        \section[~]{\centering}
        \appendixtitle{type}{appendix title}
        \newlength{\celllen}
        \setlength{\celllen}{\textwidth/5}
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{table}[!htb]
            \caption{multirowed}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{z{\celllen}|}}
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{\celllen}{\centering
                    very very very long cell \newline symbol \newline unit
                } & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ \textbf{   Description } } \tnl
                & value & value & value \tnl \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

        \begin{table}[!htb]
            \caption{final}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{z{\celllen}|}}
                \hline
                \multirow{5}{\celllen}{\centering
                    very very very long cell \newline symbol \newline unit
                } & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ \textbf{   Description } } \tnl
                & value & value & value \tnl \cline{2-4}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ \textbf{ Description }, symbol, unit } \tnl
                & value & value & value \tnl \cline{2-4}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ \textbf{ Description }, symbol, unit } \tnl \hline
                value \newline (comment) & value & value & value \tnl \hline
                value \newline (comment) & value & value & value \tnl \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

How can I make all those red-framed-texts (and "value" strings I forgot to frame) centered, just like other strings

P.S.
help with first table (text overflow) is greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `\newline` but `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering

aaa\\ bbbbbb\\ cccccc

aaa\newline bbbbbb\newline cccccc

\end{document}
```

And try to make simpler examples. Wading through all this `\multirow` etc doesn't make it easy to debug your code.

Comment: It's my first real LaTeX document, and first real problem, where I couldn't find answer, so please forgive me my long example here ;)

Answer (score 7):

the mechanism for `\newline` makes this command be equivalent to `\\`, so what precedes it is treated as an ordinary "paragraph" (ending with `\parfillskip` glue, messing up the centering). (you are using this inside a table, which means you shouldn't use `\\` directly.)

change `\newline` to `\break`, avoiding all fancy additions (but also all checking), and every line will center as desired.

Comment: Using `\\` to end centered lines will works fine in the example. `\\` to end tabular lines will not work in the cell with `centering`, so you should `\tabularnewline` instead (or give `\\` the "end tabular line" meaning back with `\\arraybackslash`)

Comment: @ulrike, sorry, your comment isn't comprehensible because the attempt to "code-ify" the double backslash isn't working correctly.  i guess i should bring that problem up on meta.  i've been burned by it several times, so now i put spaces around the two backslashes within the upticks.

Comment: @ulrike -- the double backslash mess in comments has been discussed [here on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168/backslash-in-ticks-in-comments).  seems it's not likely to change.  bummer.

Comment: @barbara beeton, thanks, your solution worked too

Comment: @barbara: Sorry I forget (again) about the problem with the backslashes. So here the hopefully corrected comment: Using ` \\ ` to end centered lines will works fine in the example. ` \\ ` to end tabular lines will not work in the cell with centering, so you should \tabularnewline instead (or give ` \\ ` the "end tabular line" meaning back with ` \arraybackslash `)